# Attempting to set the box constraints of a Row widget in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, constraints, textfield

Okay, so I'm using Flutter, and trying to set constraints of an entire Row widget to the
width of the screen, NOT set the constraints of each individual part of the row.  I've searched
everywhere, and a Row widget does not HAVE a width or max width parameter to set (It sets it to
infinity for some reason) and ONE of the two things inside the row HAS to be a textfield (I'm
developing on iOS so I'm using a CupertinoTextField, but that shouldn't make a difference.

An example of the body of a scaffold widget would be:

```
  body: Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(new Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, double.infinity)),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        CupertinoTextField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          onSubmitted: (value) {
            notes = value;
          },
          controller: textInput,
        ),
      ], 
    )
  )
```

As you can imagine, I'm getting unbounded render box errors, as the row is NOT getting bounded
properly, and I have no idea why Flutter won't let me set the counting box for the entire row.
(Or if it does, it's not doing it in the way I'm doing!)

Results of Flutter Doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.14.2-pre.20, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale
    en-CA)
    • Flutter version 1.14.2-pre.20 at /Users/iosdev/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision 91f8d3da32 (2 hours ago), 2020-01-16 18:21:16 +0000
    • Engine revision e0fe834288
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.2.0 009537bbf0)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/iosdev/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
      support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Phillip’s iPhone • 52a4fba45a6767b88e4dddd881201205138cac0e • ios • iOS
      13.3

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap your CupertinoTextField with an Expanded widget:

```
Container(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: CupertinoTextField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          onSubmitted: (value) {
            notes = value;
          },
          controller: textInput,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
)
```